# Database insertion fails without error with scrapy

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, scrapy, python-dataset

[image]

I'm working with scrapy and dataset (https://dataset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#storing-data) which is a layer on top of sqlalchemy , trying to load data into a sqllite table as a follow up to [Sqlalchemy : Dynamically create table from Scrapy item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41106509/sqlalchemy-dynamically-create-table-from-scrapy-item).

using the dataset package I have:

```
class DynamicSQLlitePipeline(object):

    def __init__(self,table_name):

        db_path = "sqlite:///"+settings.SETTINGS_PATH+"\\data.db"
        db = dataset.connect(db_path)
        self.table = db[table_name].table


    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        try:
            print('TEST DATASET..')
            self.table.insert(dict(name='John Doe', age=46, country='China'))
            print('INSERTED')
        except IntegrityError:
                print('THIS IS A DUP')
        return item
```

after running my spider I see the print statements printed out in the try except block, with no errors, but after completion , I look in the table and see the screenshot. No data is in the table. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted is not working as is for me:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

That's because the `__init__` method expects a `table_name` argument which is not being passed. You need to implement the `from_crawler` class method in the pipeline object, something like:

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    return cls(table_name=crawler.spider.name)
```

That would create a pipeline object using the spider name as table name, you can of course use any name you want.

Also, the line `self.table = db[table_name].table` should be replaced by `self.table = db[table_name]` (https://dataset.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#storing-data)

After that, the data is stored:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I removed  the @classmethod from my code, to simplify it. sorry. Thank you. BTW what db gui are you using?

Comment: Actually, the @classmethod decorator is necessary because the from_crawler method is invoked as a class method :-)
As for the GUI, it's http://sqlitebrowser.org

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask 1 more question: is it it possible to set the order of the fields given that the dict passed to the insert command is unordered?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some problems with the Db connection. Put your this snippet into a try except to check for the problem.

```
try:
   db_path = "sqlite:///"+settings.SETTINGS_PATH+"\\data.db"
   db = dataset.connect(db_path)
   self.table = db[table_name].table
except Exception:
   traceback.exec_print()
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. tried it, no errors. Also added   print(db.tables) to the code, and the correct tables are printed out in a list as expected, so it appears the connection is OK.