# Sequential Order for Item Output | Scrapy

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, scrapinghub

I am using a ScrapingHub API, and am using shub, to deploy my project. However, the items result is in as shown:

[image: Example Item Output]

Unfortunately, I need it in the following order --> Title, Publish Date, Description, Link. How can I get the output to be in exactly that order for every item class?

Below is a short sample of my spider:

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.spiders import XMLFeedSpider
from tickers.items import tickersItem
class Spider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = "Scraper"
    allowed_domains = ["yahoo.com"]
    start_urls = ('https://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=ABIO,ACFN,AEMD,AEZS,AITB,AJX,AU,AKERMN,AUPH,AVL,AXPW
                  'https://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=DRIO
                  'https://feeds.finance.yahoo.com/rss/2.0/headline?s=IDXG,IMMU,IMRN,IMUC,INNV,INVT,IPCI,INPX,JAGX,KDMN,KTOV,LQMT
                  )
    itertag = 'item'

    def parse_node(self, response, node):
        item = {}
        item['Title'] = node.xpath('title/text()',).extract_first()
        item['Description'] = node.xpath('description/text()').extract_first()
        item['Link'] = node.xpath('link/text()').extract_first()
        item['PublishDate'] = node.xpath('pubDate/text()').extract_first()
        return item
```

Additionally, here is my attached items.py file, it is in the same order as my spider, so  I have no idea why the output is not in order.

Items.py:

```
import scrapy

class tickersItem(scrapy.Item):
    Title = scrapy.Field()
    Description = scrapy.Field()
    Link = scrapy.Field()
    PublishDate = scrapy.Field()
```

The syntax of my code is in order for both the items and the spider file, and I have no idea how to fix it. I am a new python programmer.

Comment: Avoid external link and prefer embeded content for you image please.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of defining items in `items.py`, you could use [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). Just import `collections` module and in `parse_node` method, change the line:

```
item = {}
```

to line:

```
item = collections.OrderedDict()
```

Or, if you want defined items, you could use approach outlined in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41301998/5832540). Your `items.py` would then contain this code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

from scrapy import Field, Item
import six

class OrderedItem(Item):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._values = OrderedDict()
        if args or kwargs:  # avoid creating dict for most common case
            for k, v in six.iteritems(dict(*args, **kwargs)):
                self[k] = v

class tickersItem(OrderedItem):
    Title = Field()
    Description = Field()
    Link = Field()
    PublishDate = Field()
```

You should then also modify your spider code to use this item, accordingly. Refer to the [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html).

Comment: Do I have to clear my items.py file? Or can I just add the suggested code to my code

Comment: I edited the answer and added the code for `items.py`.